# Mongodb: query embedded document for value comparator

Tags: mongodb

I have a Movies collection with multiple documents which are embedding 'results' subdocuments (one to many):

```
{
    "_id" : 19,
    "name" : "Star wars",
    "results" : [
        {
            "type" : "type1",
            "score" : 44.51211101958831
        },
        {
            "type" : "type2",
            "score" : 0.6578497966368002
        },
        {
            "type" : "type3",
            "score" : 93.36341655949683
        },
        {
            "type" : "type3",
            "score" : 49.43132782777443
        }
    ]
}
```

How to remove the lowest `type3 score` for each movie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) framework. Here is example on Node.js:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('zips');

    collection.aggregate(
        {
            '$unwind':'$results' // expand results array
        },
        {
            '$group':
            {
                '_id':'$_id', // group results by id
                'min':
                {
                    '$min':'$results.score' // and get minimal score 
                }
            }
        },
        function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            console.log(results);
        }
    );   
});
```

Loop through `results` array to update your collection using `$pull` operator.

```
collection.update(
    {
        '_id': results[i]._id 
    }, 
    {
        '$pull': { 'results': { 'score': results[i].min }   } 
    },
    function(err, updated) {
        // update callback
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Artem, however I've added a `$match` to `aggregate()` so as to filter the score type.

Comment: Yep, I miss the type, glad to help.